# how can I fix ssrs report design issue?

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

i need to pass certain fixed set of parameters from a common interface to call ssrs reports.
which are not actually used in my stored procedure for my particular ssrs report so how do i handle that any suggestions.
i need to pass @ORGcode,@status ,@fromDate,@toDate and my stored procedure only needs @fromDate,@toDate .

Comment: Can u pls Elaborate? What is the need of  @ORGcode,@status   then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create the two additional parameters in the ssrs report and don't use them.
you can create the variables by right clicking the parameters folder in your report data window and selecting Add parameter.